# CVS or SVN or GIT?

Tags: svn, git, version-control, cvs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Revision Control System Recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640133/revision-control-system-recommendations)

I'm in the middle of developing a web app. Which version control system (CVS/SVN/GIT) is recommended for managing a web app (it's environment is PHP/MySQL, Apache 2, Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit server)?

The web app is being developed on a dev/sandbox server for now, but will eventually be hosted on dedicated servers in the cloud when its private beta and then launch time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Revision Control System Recommendations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640133/revision-control-system-recommendations) and [SCM choice for a new user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420566/scm-choice-for-a-new-user)

Comment: I wouldnt even consider CVS if i were you. Im partial to SVN over Git myself - mainly because i prefer `svn:externals` to git submodules... but i mean really thats a pretty small thing.

Comment: @prodigitalson: Have a look at `git-subtree`.

Answer (score 21):

Once upon a time, *cvs* almost completely replaced its competition and ruled the world of version control.

Then it was itself replaced by *svn*.

And now, svn has been replaced by *git* and [github.](http://www.github.com/)

*Git*, *Mercurial*, and some proprietary systems are clearly the future of the VCS world.

Comment: Why do popular VCS's keep getting replaced relatively quickly?

Comment: It wasn't quick, the above process took 20 years. (CVS was first released in 1990.)  Prior to CVS, revision control applied mainly to single files, though you could always say `*.c`.  CVS introduced the idea of keeping track of projects and hierarchies. Then svn was basically a from-scratch rewrite of cvs. Git and Mercurial introduced the *distributed* and *branch-aware* VCS, both quite important features and worth tossing svn overboard for.

Comment: Its really not that big a learning curve and there are many good examples out there.